# Python or Perl Parse Text report file to CVS

Tags: python, perl, parsing

I have some data that I need to parse into a tab-delimited text file. The data look like:

```
>beer/name: Sausa Weizen beer/beerId: 47986 beer/brewerId: 10325 beer/ABV: 5.00 beer/style: Hefeweizen review/appearance: 2.5
> review/aroma: 2 review/palate: 1.5 review/taste: 1.5 review/overall:
> 1.5 review/time: 1234817823 review/profileName: stcules review/text: A lot of foam. But a lot.    In the smell some banana, and then lactic and
> tart. Not a good start.   Quite dark orange in color, with a lively
> carbonation (now visible, under the foam).    Again tending to lactic
> sourness. Same for the taste. With some yeast and banana.     
> 
> beer/name: Red Moon ...repeats millions of times...
```

`
I need it to look like this:

> Sausa Weizen {tab} 47986 {tab} 10325 {tab} ...

Does anyone have some example perl code that I could use to get started? I am new to Perl and I tinkered around with some other examples I found on the site but could not get them working in my context.

I've tried using regular expressions in Vim and also the following perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#parse_file_kv.pl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $save_input_record_separator = $/; #Save original value before changing it
undef $/; # enable slurp mode
open(my $file ,"ratebeer.txt");
$/ = $save_input_record_separator; #Restore original value to this global variable
my %h = $file =~ m/\w+/g;#Read keys and values from file into hash %h
for (keys %h){
    print "KeyWord $_ has value $h{$_}.\n";
}
print "\n";
my @kws2find = qw(beer/name);
foreach ( @kws2find ){
    find_value($_);
}
sub find_value{
    my $kw = shift @_;
    if (exists $h{$kw}){
        print "Value of $kw is $h{$kw}\n";
    }else{
        print "Keyword $kw is not found in hash\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Perl, there are many ways to do this, but I'll give the most minimal:

```
# a sample input line.  In reality you would read it from a file and chomp off the \n.
my $foo = "beer/name: Sausa Weizen beer/beerId: 47986 ...\n";

# replace foo/bar: with a tab everywhere in the line.  
# I used A-Za-z as the chars to match, you can do many more things (including more
# elegant ways of specifying whole character classes).
#
$foo =~ s/[A-Za-z]*\/[a-zA-Z]*:/\t/g;

# print it out.
print "$foo\n";
```